# Need help debugging my first program, Visual Studio cant find the .exe file.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

This is my first program its to calculate commute cost. Visual Studio is having issues debugging so Im looking for some help...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int miles, gallons, gallonCost, mpg, mileCost, parking, tolls, FuelCost, TotalCost = 0.0;
```

Can someone explain what the above line is doing (or not doing) is it a correct way to make a list of float integers?

```
cout << " How many miles do you drive per day? ";
    cin >> miles;

cout << " What is the price per gallon of fuel? ";
    cin << gallonCost;

cout << " How many gallons of fuel do you use per day? ";
    cin >> gallons;

mpg = miles / gallons;
mileCost = gallonCost / mpg;

cout << " Your fuel efficentcy is " << mpg ;" miles per gallon. ";
cout << " Your fuel cost is $" << mileCost ;" per mile. "; 

    FuelCost = mileCost * miles;

cout << " Your paying $" << FuelCost ;" for fuel per day.";

cout << " What are you daily parking fees? ";
    cin << parking;

cout << " How much do you spend on Tolls each day? ";
    cin >> tolls;

TotalCost = parking + tolls + FuelCost;

cout << " Your driving cost is $" << TotalCost ;" per day." endl;

system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is float integer????????

Comment: I guess he meant float number.

Comment: Before you try to debug you must make sure that the compile was successful fixing all compile errors and addressing any compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

No that is not the way to create floating point variables, but the way to create integer variables. There is no such things as "float integers".

You should also get a lot of warnings about expressions not doing anything, like in the line

```
cout << " Your fuel efficentcy is " << mpg ;" miles per gallon. ";
//                            Problem here ^
```

That is because you have an extra semicolon in the middle of the line, thereby terminating the output statement. Then the compiler finds a string, which is the same as an expression so it's okay but doesn't do anything which should cause a warning. Instead of the extra semicolon I suspect you wanted the output operator `<<`.

And you should be getting an error on this line:

```
cout << " Your driving cost is $" << TotalCost ;" per day." endl;
//                                              Error here ^
```

That error is because you have a string followed by an identifier. This is not a valid expression. You probably forgot the output operator `<<` here.

It's this last error that causes the build process to not create an executable, so you can't run/debug. Always pay attention to the messages produced by the compiler, even warnings will tell you something useful.